# Change prefix in a integer column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to convert the prefix from `222..` to `999..` in pyspark.
Expected  new column `new_id` with changed prefixt to `999..`s

I will be using this column for inner merge b/w 2 pysparl dataframes

| id | new_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2222238308750 | 9999938308750 |
| 222222579844 | 999999579844 |
| 222225701296 | 999995701296 |
| 2222250087899 | 9999950087899 |
| 2222250087899 | 9999950087899 |
| 2222237274658 | 9999937274658 |
| 22222955099 | 99999955099 |
| 22222955099 | 99999955099 |
| 22222955099 | 99999955099 |
| 222285678 | 999985678 |

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with something like this,

```
# First calculate the number of "2"s from the start till some other value is found, for eg '2223' should give you 3 as the length
# Use that calculated value to repeat the "9" that many times
# replace starting "2"s with the calulated "9" string
# finally drop all the calculated columns
df.withColumn("len_2", F.length(F.regexp_extract(F.col("value"), r"^2*(?!2)", 0)).cast('int'))\
    .withColumn("to_replace_with", F.expr("repeat('9', len_2)"))\
    .withColumn("new_value", F.expr("regexp_replace(value, '^2*(?!2)', to_replace_with)")) \
    .drop("len_2", "to_replace_with")\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|value        |new_value    |
+-------------+-------------+
|2222238308750|9999938308750|
|222222579844 |999999579844 |
|222225701296 |999995701296 |
|2222250087899|9999950087899|
|2222250087899|9999950087899|
|2222237274658|9999937274658|
|22222955099  |99999955099  |
|22222955099  |99999955099  |
|22222955099  |99999955099  |
|222285678    |999985678    |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I have used the column name as `value`, you would have to substitute it with `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = df.withColumn("tempcol1", regexp_extract("id", "^2*", 0)).withColumn("tempcol2", split(regexp_replace("id", "^2*", "_"), "_")[1]).withColumn("new_id", concat((regexp_replace("tempcol1", "2", "9")), "tempcol2")).drop("tempcol1", "tempcol2")
```

The id column is split into two temp columns, one having the prefix and the other the rest of the string. The prefix column values are replaced and concatenated back with the second temp column.

Comment: This will only match `22222`, not all the starting `2`'s.

Comment: Could you paste the previous answer as well? want to have a look which maches only 22222 to 99999

Comment: df = df.withColumn("new_id", regexp_replace("id", "^22222", "99999"))